# Regex for creating paragraphs

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to add paragraphs to a text but they should not start with h* tags and they should not be empty.

I have this regex to create p tags for every line:

```
/^(.*)$/mg
```

usage:

```
text.replace(/^(.*)$/mg, function(match, contents, offset, input_string) {
    return '<p>'+contents+'</p>';
});
```

How can I check if paragraph is empty or starting with tags like h1, h2 etc.?

Comment: *" they should not start with and ..."*! With what?

Comment: `.+` instead of `.*` and negative lookup probably.

Comment: @Shafizadeh header tags

Comment: So you mean something like this? https://regex101.com/r/qLmna0/2

Comment: @Shafizadeh Yes, it works. Thanks.

Comment: Put a real world input in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add `<p>` tag surround a text which is neither empty not starts with `<header>` tag, this pattern would work:

```
/^(?!<h)(.+)$/
```

And the replace it with: `<p>$1</p>`.

#### [Online Demo](https://regex101.com/r/qLmna0/4)

Comment: You forgot to exclude heading elements.

Comment: @revo Not sure what you mean exactly, but as you can see, the first line in [this](https://regex101.com/r/qLmna0/3) is a header element.. Isn't it?